# How to generate word document(docx) with 1000+ images using firebase (Firestore and Storage)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Database : Firebase Firestore

Images : Firebase Storage

I need to create a word document with the data from Firestore and images from Firebase storage. That document will have 1000+ images with data. How to achieve this effectively using firebase cloud function?

Comment: what do you mean by "word document"?

Comment: I mean word document(.docx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe using Cloud Functions for this use case is the best. You are trying to create a word document with so much data (more than 1000+). This will take time and your function may timeout before it finishes its job.

better to use the admin sdk in an environment of your choose (like your local machine or GCP compute engine). Then programmatically (with a language of your choice) grab the data from both firestore and storage  and save them in a new word document.

for more info about firebase admin sdk, check [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: can you suggest me some framework? like Laravel. Can I go for that approach?

Comment: Hi, I showed you the path and choosing a language depends on you to do this task. if you check the documentation you can see all the supported languages. Laravel is PHP and it's not listed there so you cannot use it. try another language like Nodejs or Python.

Comment: I tried with Nodejs also. Still not working for 1000+ images.

Comment: can you explain in details what do you mean by it "still not working"? provide: code, graphs, error messages, logs